# How better convert all Set elements in java?

Tags: java, performance, set, loops

I have set like:

```
Set<String>
```

I need on each element of Set make split by ; and create new Set that will contain only 2-nd element. Should I make it directly one by one or exists better way?
Thanks.

Comment: You will need to iterate through the set and manipulate each element one by one.

Comment: and while you're at it, don't forget to use `StringBuilder`

Comment: how I can use StringBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can relax your constraint of an output being a `Set<String>` to being a `Collection<String>` you could use Guava and defer the transformation of elements until enumeration of elements through the [Collections2#transform()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method. You would just have to write a custom function to perform the split on an individual element.

But if you cannot/should not relax this constraint, you are best left to doing the already proposed individual iterations (as it'd be much more legible).

Code would look something like:

```
Set<String> input; //Given
Collection<String> output = Collections2.transform(input, new Function<String,String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply (String element) {
        // As JohnnyO says, add appropriate edge case checking...
        return element.split(";")[1]; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Set<String> suffixSet = new HashSet<String>();
for (String s : inputSet) {
      suffixSet.add(s.split(";")[1])
}
```

I'd also add appropriate error checking and handling for the case when s does not have a ; present.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not shown the code, we can only guess what you're trying to do. You need to iterate through the `Set` and split each `String`. You can use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method if you want.

Comment: like: outputSet = new HashSet<String>(); for(String entry:inputSet) {String[] values=entry.split(";"); outputSet.add(values[1]); }

Comment: That's how you _create_ a HashSet. Edit: As @JohnnyO mentions it.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say with so little information. You could iterate over the set doing `split` and adding to another `Set`.
Or you could replace `Set` with a e.g. `HashMap` and when you create the map put as key the first part of the string and as value the second so that you can retrieve the second part when you need fast.
Or if you create the strings yourself place them in different sets directly
Or...(you don't say enough) to provide more options